# CFT calculation of the Partitionfunction of $2+1$ dimensional gravity

Tags: quantum-gravity, conformal-field-theory, partition-function

I want to reproduce formula (4.29) in http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1773v1 given by:

$$
Z=Tr(q^{L_{0}}\bar q^{\bar L_{0}})=|q|^{-2k} \prod^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{1}{|1-q^{n}|^{2}}
$$

Where the trace is over an irreducible representation of the Virasoro algebra with an groundstate of weight $(h,\bar h)=(-k,-k)$.

When I'm correct one can use the formula for the character of the Verma module 
$$
  \chi_{(c,h)}(\tau)=Tr(q^{L_{0}-c/24})= q^{h-c/24} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{n}}.
$$

With 
$$
  \chi_{(0,-k)}(\tau)=Tr(q^{L_{0}})= q^{-k} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{n}}
$$
and
$$
  \bar\chi_{(0,-k)}(\bar\tau)=Tr(\bar q^{\bar L_{0}})= \bar q^{-k} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\bar q^{n}}
$$
I get
$$
Z_{my}=\chi_{(0,-k)}(\tau) \bar\chi_{(0,-k)}(\bar\tau)=|q|^{-2k} \prod^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{|1-q^{n}|^{2}}
$$

1.) My product starts at $n=1$ and I not see why I could ignore the first contribution. Where is my mistake?

2.) Why do they set the $c=0$?

Comment: see the answer in http://www.physicsoverflow.org/24418/